# System.TypeException: Cannot call test methods in non-test context

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, salesforce1-app

Hi i have a test class but it gives following error

**error :** 
Line: -1, Column: -1
System.TypeException: Cannot call test methods in non-test context

**Code**

```
@isTest
public class testclass {    
     public static testMethod void testMe() {
            test.startTest();
            WebServiceCallout.sendNotification('1','2',
                                           '3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11',
                                           '12','13','14','15',16,'17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25');

            test.stopTest();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your class is annotated with `@isTest`. This means that it's a test class. You cannot call it from Apex or anonymous Apex. You can only run it by running the tests (which you can do in the dev console).

Edit: your method itself needs the `@isTest` annotation to be ran as a test method; otherwise, this is just a class with (supposedly) a helper method for your test contexts.